# func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) gives warning and suggests making private

Tags: xcode

I just ported from Xcode 7 to Xcode 8.1.  The declaration

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

gives the warning

> instance method `tableView(...didSelectRowAt:)` nearly matches optional requirement `tableView(...selectorForSectionIndexTitle:at)` of protocol `UITableViewDataSource`.

The suggested fix it gives is to make `tableView` private.  If is select this the warning is removed but I start getting exception breakpoints on lines that do not make sense and when i do not have an exception breakpoint setup in the breakpoint navigator.

So far I have simply left the warnings in (this problem shows up on all 6 of my viewControllers).

Comment: The break shows "Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1" so this is not a break due to a failure.

Comment: After looking an a number of pages on exception breakpoints I added an exception breakpoint and it still breaks at the same line.  I added to the action "po $arg1" and nothing shows in the system window.  If I enter "po $arg1" I get a complaint about $arg1 being an unresolved reference.  Looking at the line where it is a simple if stmt and I can enter the condition being tested in the system window and it gives a "true" as it should

Comment: Very strange.  I have no idea why I seem to be breaking at this point.  It is in  a tableView call to get the indexPath of a selected row.  This is an expected call (just not a break) and I can continue on from this break.  Unfortunately it doesn't call the tableView func for processing the selection.

Comment: It turns out that i changed the tableView func for processing the selection to "private" due to a warning and following the Xcode suggestion to eliminate the warning.  Just due to superstition I removed the "private" and the warning came back but now it runs like it should!  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Sorry, but looking at the stackoverflow site I can't see how to delete questions.

Comment: Can anyone help me in how to delete questions in stackoverflow?

Comment: As you suggested I have re-edited the question completely and given it a new title.  So you can delete all of your comments and re-use this question.  Early you indicated that "I know how to fix this king of thing!".  How can I fix it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that this is a UITableViewDelegate method. Therefore it must be *inside* a declaration that *adopts* UITableViewDelegate.

For example, let's say your class is called MyViewController. Then you would write:

```
extension MyViewController : UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
        didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This fixed it.  I moved my tableView function from my extension UITableViewTableSource to my extension UITableViewDelegate as you suggested and my warnings go away and everything continues to work.